# Mime mail system attaching two files

Tags: 7, emails, mimemail

I am trying to send pdf through using mime mail module + mailsystem module + smtp authentication module

```
function send_mail(){
$to='xx@gmail.com'; $subject='xxxx'; $message='aaaaa';
$from='x123@gmail.com';
$my_mail_token = microtime();
$message = array(
'id' => $my_module . '_' . $my_mail_token,
'to' => $to,
'subject' => $subject,
'body' => array($message),
'headers' => array(
'From' => $from,
'Sender' => $from,
'Return-Path' => $from,
'Content-type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
 ),
);
 $attached=$message['params']['attachments'][]  = array(
'filename' => $filename,
'path' =>DRUPAL_ROOT.'sites/default/files/pdf'.'/'.$uid.'/'.$filename,
'filecontent' => file_get_contents('sites/default/files/pdf'.'/'.$uid.'/'.$filename),
'mime' => 'application/pdf',
'Content-type' => 'application/octet-stream',
'encoding' => 'base64',
'disposition' => 'attachment',
'list' => TRUE
);
$system = drupal_mail_system($my_module, $my_mail_token);
//unlink('sites/default/files/pdf'.'/'.$uid.'/'.$filename);
$message = $system->format($message);
if ($system->mail($message)) {
return TRUE;
}
else {
return FALSE;
    }
}
```

This is the code its sending two files as mail attachments instead of one. Why its doing that i cant understand. Looking for help.

Comment: What function is it in?

Comment: I have editted the code mow you can find in insde the send_mail() function

Comment: This happens usually when you provide both filepath and filecontent. Please check this answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/186157